# How to add username in welcome email after registration?

Tags: laravel-5

I've been searching everywhere for a solution to my issue. I've created a welcome email, created the Mailable, Controller, and View. But for some reason, the $user isn't showing in the email itself. It's blank. Am I missing something?

Mailable

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Mail;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;


class Welcome extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $user; 
    /**
    * @return void
    */
    public function _construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    /**
    *@return $this
    */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('emails.welcome')->subject('Welcome to');
    }
}
```

Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Mail;
use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Http\Mail\Welcome;



class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/dashboard';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'first_name' => 'required|max:255',
            'last_name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'mobile' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        $user = User::create([
                            'first_name' => $data['first_name'],
                            'last_name' => $data['last_name'],
                            'email' => $data['email'],
                            'mobile' => $data['mobile'],
                            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
                            'payment_mode' => 'CASH',
                            ]);



        Mail::to($data['email'])->send(new Welcome($user));

        return $user;
        // send welcome email here
    }


    /**
     * Show the application registration form.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */

    public function showRegistrationForm()
    {

        return view('user.auth.register');
    }

}
```

View (shortened to show problem)

```
Welcome {{ $user->first_name }}
```

User

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens,Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'mobile', 'picture', 'password', 'device_type','device_token','login_by', 'payment_mode','social_unique_id','device_id','wallet_balance'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token', 'created_at', 'updated_at'
    ];
}
```

As was mentioned, everything passes successfully, however, in the email itself, the name of the user is blank. Please help!

Comment: did you add first_name to the $fillable array within User Model?

Comment: How did the `create` controller is trigger? Did It be execute after submitting some form? has I know controller receive as arguments URL parameters in case of form submit with `method` attribute set to `GET` or It can take a $request object if you submit with `POST` method. Could you `dump` the result of `$data` which is pass to the create controller and show the result. If It's isn't the case check the result of `$user` variable to ensure the given user is create successfully

Comment: @Thamerbelfkih yes it is fillable.

Comment: @YvesKipondo Yes the create controller creates the user in the database just fine.

Comment: Can you share your user model please!

Comment: @Emerg did your `dd($user)` and check all that the data for `user` you are getting?

Comment: @Thamerbelfkih question updated with user

Comment: @MuhammadShareyar where would I put dd($user)?

Comment: In your email template `{{dd($user)}}` in place of  `Welcome {{ $user->first_name }}`

Comment: @MuhammadShareyar Weird it says "null". But everything updates fine in my database.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working for anyone else dealing with same issue. I changed the register controller and just skipped the mailable entirely. In other words, I didn't need a separate mailable. Below is the result.

```
Mail::send('emails.welcome', [
            'first_name' => $data['first_name'],
            'email' => $data['email']
            ], function ($mail) use($data) {
                $mail->from('Whatever', 'site/company name');

                $mail->to($data['email'])->subject('Whatever');
            });
return $user;
```

And in the view I just pass the first name like so

```
Welcome {{ $first_name }}
```